# Navigation View selecting multiple items

Tags: android, xml, navigation

I implemented the Navigation View (Support Library 24.0.0):

But a strange behavior occurred in which i have been trying to control since.

Here is my `drawer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Categories">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_news"
                    android:title="Top Stories" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_music"
                    android:title="Entertainment" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_3"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sport"
                    android:title="Sport" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_4"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_lifestyle"
                    android:title="Lifestyle" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_5"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tech"
                    android:title="Technology" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_6"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_world"
                    android:title="International" />

            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

But the result is :

[image: The Result Image]

in which only one should be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using :

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    MenuItem top = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i);
                    if (top.isChecked()) top.setChecked(false);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

1. Unchecking all items in the menu
2. `return true`, that checks the clicked item.